# xdt transform adding redundant namespace

Tags: xml, transformation, xdt

When using xdt transformation on a xml file which is using xml schema namespace, is there any approach which doesn't add a redundant namespace of a replaced element?

Input:

```
<myrootnode xmlns="http://myschema">
  <thenode>myOLDvalue</thenode>
</myrootnode>
```

Transform:

```
<s:myrootnode xmlns:s="http://myschema" xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <s:thenode xdt:Transform="Replace">myNEWvalue</s:thenode>
</s:myrootnode>
```

Output:

```
<myrootnode xmlns="http://myschema">
  <s:thenode xmlns:s="http://myschema">myNEWvalue</s:thenode>
</myrootnode>
```

I've also tried using XPath locator, with the same result. Transform:

```
<myrootnode xmlns:s="http://myschema" xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <s:thenode xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="XPath(//s:thenode)">myNEWvalue</s:thenode>
</myrootnode>
```

I would like this output:

```
<myrootnode xmlns="http://myschema">
  <thenode>myNEWvalue</thenode>
</myrootnode>
```

Is it possible using xdt?

Comment: From an *informational* point of view `<s:thenode xmlns:s="http://myschema">myNEWvalue</s:thenode>` and `<thenode>myNEWvalue</thenode>` when nested within an element that defines the default namespace as `http://myschema` are *exactly* the same data. Is this actually causing a problem for you, and if so, why are you trying to fix the wrong part? (fix the part that has an issue processing this XML, because it is *wrong*)

Comment: I know it's technically correct. It might work. It will probably work. But I don't know. To make any guarantee the result will work there shouldn't be any redundant namespaces. It's also easier to read and cheaper to maintain if the result is as simple as possible.